# Rails and Devise - Add a Field To Log-In

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, devise

I have set up a blog with secure log-in using the Devise plugin and its working well. I'm going to add an additional 'username' field at sign-up and article posts will then display this info. How do I achieve this so the username goes into the db - any code help would be appreciated?

User names will need to be unique but I will look into this later.

Answer (score 8):

As the Devise wiki sez:

Create a migration

```
rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string
```

Run the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

Modify the User model and add username to attr_accessible

```
 attr_accessible :username
```

more info [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

For uniqueness you could just do a validation on the User model

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have read the Devise wiki and it still doesn't really help. I want users to always sign in with their email address - but want to capture their 'screen' username on 'sign-up' so that when they post an article their 'username' (and not email address) is posted beside it.

Comment: the article teaches (among others) how to add a username field in the user model. then, after the user inserts his username (at signup maybe?) you can use it wherever you want in your application. You might want to generate the views for the devise registration controller so that you can actually put a username field in the form for a user to enter @signup

Comment: Yea, you'll do as described above and add the field to the form (generate them first). Make sure you add attr_accessible as mentioned in this answer - I burnt a lot of time by missing this.

Comment: @chance @andrei Thanks all... got it working and the articles now display the username and not email addresses! On the sign-up form I now need it to make sure a username is entered and its unique? Any ideas...

Comment: for uniqueness and presence put `validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true` in your user model

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you have 2 questions in the same topic.

The first one has been answered and you followed these steps: [Add custom fields to devise](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/)

Then for your next question: the problem isn't the user but `@article` because this variable is `nil`. So Rails can't find the `User` related to something that is `nil`.

You should post your controller and your `_article` view so I can help further.

Also I don't understand what you meant by :

> I changed the object from 'email' to 'username' to stop it showing the submitters email address in the article

..You can choose whatever you want to display without replacing anything. If you want to display the user's username, just do `user.username`

Answer (score 0):

- add `belongs_to :user` in your article.rb and `has_many :articles` to your user.rb
- update your migration of article to include a user_id:integer field (or use `t.references :user`)
- update your ArticlesController#create action to use `current_user.create_article` or `build_article`
- be sure to invoke the authenticate_user! before_filter for the :create action
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only => :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

ref:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html